# Using TFS API to rollback a changeset

Tags: api, tfs, rollback, workspace

I am trying to use the TFS API to rollback a changeset.
I tried using all Workspace.Rollback methods but the action does nothing (The GetStatus returned says NoActionNeeded:true).
Has anyone managed to get this to work and can send a working code sample?

From the documentation of the method:
public GetStatus Rollback(
    string[] paths,
    RecursionType recursion,
    VersionSpec itemSpecVersion,
    VersionSpec versionFrom,
    VersionSpec versionTo,
    LockLevel lockLevel,
    RollbackOptions options,
    string[] itemAttributeFilters
)
I do not understand what the parameter VersionSpec itemSpecVersion means.
It says 'The version spec that identifies the item to which the user is referring.' but then how does it differ from the parameter versionFrom?
What should I pass as the itemAttributeFilters (the last paramter)?

Comment: You should just set null for VersionSpec itemSpecVersion parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can rollback changeset programmatically with the following code:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tfsCollectionURL"));
        VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
        string workingDirectory = @"localPath";
        string[] workigDnirectoryArr = new string[] { workingDirectory };
        Workspace ws = vcs.GetWorkspace("$/serverPath");

        int fromCS = 456; //changesetid
        int toCS = 495; //changesetid
        VersionSpec versionSpecFrom = new ChangesetVersionSpec(fromCS);
        VersionSpec versionSpecTo = new ChangesetVersionSpec(toCS);

        var status = ws.Rollback(workigDnirectoryArr, RecursionType.None,null, versionSpecFrom, versionSpecTo,LockLevel.None,RollbackOptions.None,null);
```